# How do I restore inspect element shortcut (Q) in menu context of Firefox 70+?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition, and to my surprise, today I updated to version `70.0b1 (64 bits)` and the option to hit the "q" key to go straight to the inspected element has been disabled. I use this option for years, for me it's one of the most useful things in Firefox, I can't believe they removed it.

Is it possible to enable this option again?

[image]

Comment: I am on FF 70.0a1 (2019-08-29) (64-bit) and the shortcut Q works fine for me.

Comment: Please, update to b1 and check if works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a new shortcut, and it's much more efficient, no longer need to right click, just hovering over the element and pressing `ctrl+shift+c`.